# Get Last Quater Last date from Java date/Calender

Tags: java, date, calendar

I want to get the last quater's last date from Java Date/Calender classes.

For example :

```
If current date = 3rd Oct

Lat Quater Last Date : 30th Sept.
```

I am able to get the same using date.getMonth() methods, but since these methods are depricated, wondering if any better way to achive the same.

Comment: Please put a note for the reason of down-vote, I did not find same questions available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for date manipulation you should use `Calendar`. This may not be the most efficient way, but it works for your problem:

```
public Date calculateLastDayOfLastQuarter(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    try {
        switch (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
        case Calendar.JANUARY:
        case Calendar.FEBRUARY:
        case Calendar.MARCH:
            return sdf.parse("31.12." + (year - 1));
        case Calendar.APRIL:
        case Calendar.MAY:
        case Calendar.JUNE:
            return sdf.parse("31.03." + year);
        case Calendar.JULY:
        case Calendar.AUGUST:
        case Calendar.SEPTEMBER:
            return sdf.parse("30.06." + year);
        case Calendar.OCTOBER:
        case Calendar.NOVEMBER:
        case Calendar.DECEMBER:
            return sdf.parse("30.09." + year);
        default:
            return null;
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```